# PHP ignores file upload restrictions

Tags: php, file

I want to make 3 restrictions while regarding my file uploading
The program it works and the file uploads but for some reason they ignore the restrictions that have been made and it stores all of the files

```
<?php
      if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["size"] < 3000000){
      if ((strlen($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])<=50) && (!ctype_lower($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]))){         //The original file name must not exceed 50 characters
          
          $acceptedFileTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg","image/png"];
          $fileinfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
          $uploadedFileType = finfo_file($fileinfo, $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"]);
         

          if(in_array($uploadedFileType, $acceptedFileTypes))
          {
              if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["error"] > 0)
              {
                  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["error"] . "<br />";
              }else{
                  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"] . "<br />";
                  echo "Type: " . $uploadedFileType . "<br />";
                  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
                  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"];
                  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])){
                      echo $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                  }else{
                      //If the file does not exist, transfer the file from the temporary folder to the upload folder using the original upload name
                      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"], "upload/". $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])){
                          echo "Stored";
                      }else{
                          echo "Something went wrong while uploading.";
                      }
                  }
              }


        }else{
            echo "Invalid file type. Must be gif, jpg or jpeg.";
        }



  }else{
        echo "The file name must not exceed 50 characters";
  }

  }else{
            echo "Invalid file size. Must be less than 3MB.";
        }
```

?>

I want the program to upload only the files that are less then 3MB
and store the images that have less then 50 characters and have at least 1 uppercase letter in their name

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting 403 error max upload size?
if so, you have to change max file upload size in php.ini file